# application configuration, Bean to xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I'm using a configuration base on xml. How can I translate this java code to xml?

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
 SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
 GuavaCache cache1 = new GuavaCache("book", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build());
 GuavaCache cache2 = new GuavaCache("books", CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
             .expireAfterAccess(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
             .build());
 simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(cache1, cache2));
 return simpleCacheManager;
}
```

I have this, but I got stuck:

```
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cache1"/>
                <ref bean="cache2"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="cache1" class="org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache">
        <constructor-arg value="book" />
        <constructor-arg refer="foo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cahe1Settings" class="com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder" factory-method="newBuilder">

    </bean>
    <bean id="foo" factory-bean="cahe1Settings" factory-method="build"/>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I didn't run this code, It's not correct. I want a representation of the java code to xml, and I know that mine is worng/not finished

Comment: Could you please let me know the reason of porting the Java based configuration to XML?

Comment: I already have a large configuration on xml (I can't update it), and I found this example on internet

Comment: You can have java based configuration in tandem with XML. You need to add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />`

Comment: yep is true, but is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is working for me:

```
<bean id="cacheBuilder" class="com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder" factory-method="from">
    <constructor-arg value="expireAfterAccess=30m" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
      <set>
        <bean class="org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache">
          <constructor-arg value="mycache" />
          <constructor-arg>
            <bean factory-bean="userCacheBuilder" factory-method="build" />
          </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
      </set>
    </property>
  </bean>
```